# Access Denied when GET User Entitlement by ID using .NET Client for REST API

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to use the Azure DevOps Member Entitlement Management REST API to get a user by ID using the .NET Client.

I've set up a Personal Access Token (PAT) which includes Member Entitlement Management (Read) and Entitlements (Read), among other scopes.

When I call the [Search endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/user-entitlements-search-user-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) I get a list of `UserEntitlement`, but the [GET endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/user-entitlements-get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) throws the exception:

*Access Denied: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx needs the following permission(s) on the resource Users to perform this action: ReadExtended Users*

I don't know what this means... how do I add "ReadExtended Users" to the Users resource? I've looked through PAT scopes and user permissions and I can't find it.

Any why is it that I can list ALL users, but not get a single user by ID?? The documentation implies that the same permissions are required for both, and the returned objects are the same type (UserEntitlement).

Here's some code:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://vssps.dev.azure.com/MY_ORGANIZATION");
var credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", "PAT");
using (var connection = new VssConnection(uri, credentials))
using (var client = connection.GetClient<MemberEntitlementManagementHttpClient>())
{
  return client.GetUserEntitlementAsync(new Guid("USER_ID")).Result;
}
```

I'm using v15.131.1 of the client API, .NET Fx 4.5.2. Yes, it a bit outdated but it's based on the [Quickstart samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Quickstarts/dotnet/GraphQuickStarts) and the target project is .NET Fx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access Denied: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx needs the following permission(s) on the resource Users to perform this action: ReadExtended Users

I could reproduce this issue when run the User Entitlements - Get Rest API.

To solve this issue, you need to add the user to **Project Collection Administrators Group** in **Organization Settings -> Permissions**.

Then you could run the API successfully.

Comment: OK thanks. Unfortunately I can't try this because I can generate a PAT with scopes but I can't elevate my own permissions or add myself to admin groups. I'll accept this answer as it likely the most helpful answer solving my problem.